# Having confusion in using funty crate

Tags: rust

I was trying the `funty` crate and decided to use `Numeric` trait. But surprisingly i can use those methods provided by `Numeric` trait after removing the `funty` crate. This is my code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let num: u32 = 123;

    // Conversion methods
    let be_bytes: [u8; 4] = num.to_be_bytes();
    let le_bytes: [u8; 4] = num.to_le_bytes();
    let ne_bytes: [u8; 4] = num.to_ne_bytes();

    let from_be: u32 = u32::from_be_bytes(be_bytes);
    let from_le: u32 = u32::from_le_bytes(le_bytes);
    let from_ne: u32 = u32::from_ne_bytes(ne_bytes);

    

    println!("BE bytes: {:?}", be_bytes);
    println!("LE bytes: {:?}", le_bytes);
    println!("NE bytes: {:?}", ne_bytes);
    println!("From BE bytes: {}", from_be);
    println!("From LE bytes: {}", from_le);
    println!("From NE bytes: {}", from_ne);
    
}
```

The output is:

```
BE bytes: [0, 0, 3, 232]
LE bytes: [232, 3, 0, 0]
NE bytes: [232, 3, 0, 0]
From BE bytes: 1000
From LE bytes: 1000
From NE bytes: 1000
```

The tree is:

```
abi@hacek:~/Desktop/Rust/Trait$ cargo tree
Trait v0.1.0 (/home/abi/Desktop/Rust/Trait)
```

How is this happening????

Comment: All the methods you used are in the standard library, implemented for [u32](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.to_be_bytes) and other numeric types.

Answer (score 2):

Those methods are defined in the standard library, and can be used without any dependency. `funty` only attaches them to a trait, so they can be used in generic code.